# String Replace not replacing single quotes

Tags: c#

String not replacing Single Quotes with required characters

```
string abc = "STA\'ASTEST";
if (abc.Contains("'"))

{

abc.Replace("'", "\\'");                
}
```

Comment: Capture the result of `Replace`.

Comment: Need STA\\'ASTEST instead of STA'ASTEST.

Comment: did you try. abc = abc.Replace("'", "\\'");

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the replace but not assigning the result to any variable.

I assume you want to assign the result to `abc`

```
string abc = "STA\'ASTEST"; 

if (abc.Contains("'"))
{
      abc = abc.Replace("'", "\'");
}
```

It is also redundant to have the `if (abc.Contains("'"))` because the Replace function will only replace if the expression to replace actually exists. So you can just write:

```
abc = abc.Replace("'", "\'");
```